# Creating TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window object

Tags: c#, white-framework

How to convert `System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement` to `TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window` object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).